# Using JmsOutboundGateway async mode with MessageId instead of CorrelationID

Tags: spring, jms, spring-integration

I'm use spring-integration class JmsOutboundGateway in async mode. From documentation:

> async requires a `<reply-listener/>` it also requires a correlationKey (usually JMSCorrelationID) to be specified. If either of these conditions are not met, async is ignored.

But system, that receive my requests and send responses, write JMSMessageId from request message to JMSCorrelationID in response. I can solve this if copy generated by JmsOutboundGateway JMSCorrelationID to JMSMessageId. How can i do this in spring-integration (version spring-integration-jms 4.3.6.RELEASE)

```
<int-jms:outbound-gateway id="requestGateway"
                          connection-factory="jndiConnectionFactory"

                          request-destination="queueInput"
                          request-channel="channel.request.message"

                          reply-destination="queueOutput"
                          reply-channel="channel.response.message"

                          correlation-key="JMSCorrelationID"
                          async="true">
    <int-jms:reply-listener max-concurrent-consumers=20 
                            concurrent-consumers="10" />
  </int-jms:outbound-gateway>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a current limitation that using that style of correlation is not compatible with async, only blocking send/receive.

The issue is that the reply might be received before we get the message id so we won't know how to correlate it.

I just took a quick look at the code and I don't think it would be too difficult to make it possible if you would like to [open an 'Improvement' JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT) we will take a look.

Comment: There is a new API in JMS 2.0: `send(Message message, CompletionListener completionListener)`. We can rely on that `CompletionListener` callback before TX is commited for the async reply in the container. Olga, your client should consider do not override `JMSCorrelationID` if it isn't empty.

Comment: your client should consider do not override JMSCorrelationID if it isn't empty - you mean application that send responses for my requests ?